# How to implement a dynamic routing table using a dictionary?

Tags: list, dictionary, erlang, publish-subscribe

I need to implement a routing table for my publish-subscribe system based on content. I figured I should use a dictionary, something like this:

```
Routing_table = (Node_1: A, B; Node_2: X, Y; Node_3: A, Y)
```

Where Node_X is a node, values are content (messages) being sent. I can't wrap my head around implementing this, I'm fairly new to functional programming so I don't understand how to use a list or dictionary when you can't change variables.

Also is there a function that puts keys from a dictionary into the list?

Comment: The code snippet you show is not erlang, it looks like Elixir, if it is the case you should add it in the tag list. Also, your question is confusing: in Erlang a Node is more or less a virtual machine process. you cannot send any message to it, but to processes running on this node. So you should rethink/reword your question.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials that show how to fill up immutable containers. Looking at function signature should be enough to understand it. Try to write some code and if it wouldn't work, introduce it here.

Comment: Can you point me at some tutorials you mentioned? I'm not getting anything from Google, probably my query is not good enough...

Comment: The best site I know to start (and progress) with Erlang is [LearnYouSomeErlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `dict` module in erlang, the link is http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html.

the dict's key is the node name,
the dict's value is a list, just like: [A, B].